# Transaction failed due to "out of gas"

Tags: ico, out-of-gas

I sent Ether to a contract but the transaction failed due to "out of gas".

How do I complete the transaction I am trying to make? I sent the ether from my NanoS wallet to the XYO contract.

Comment: After rewording the question, I think the reason that it was put on hold no longer applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to raise you gas limit. Somewhere you should see a field called "gas limit" or "max gas". It is often set to 21,000 as default. Do you see that? Try raising the number to for example 200,000. By looking at other values sent to this contract, you can get an idea about how much gas is required.Your transaction will fail if your gas limit is below this value.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe6f6fc478b8b60defcf80a552f737d29e20e17cfeaee60a80a2a7e56fd69b9b5

What program are you using to create the transaction? Can you tell me its name? Then I might be able to answer more precisely.

Comment: I use the NanoS Wallet

Comment: So the software is also called NanoS Wallet? Try looking for the fields that I described: "gas limit" or "max gas". If you cannot find them, look for "Advanced options" or something like that.

Comment: Are you using myetherwallet.com along with NanoS?

Comment: I did find the "gas limit" under the "advanced" section and raised the gas - the transaction was successful. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If this solved your problem, could you mark this answer as accepted?